# How to access the variable defined in outer method from innner method

Tags: python

I have a simple python code as follows:

```
def outer():
    x = None
    y = None
    z = None

    def set():
        x = 1
        y = "Y"
        z = 2

    def get():
        return x, y, z

    set()
    m, s, n = get()
    print("%s, %s, %s" % (m, s, n))


outer()
```

I would like to get `1 Y 2`, but the result is `None None None`.

It looks that the variable x,y,z is not set by the `set` method,

I would ask how to get the result `1 Y 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the `nonlocal` keyword.

```py
def outer():
    x = None
    y = None
    z = None

    def set():
        nonlocal x
        nonlocal y
        nonlocal z
        x = 1
        y = "Y"
        z = 2

    def get():
        return x, y, z

    set()
    m, s, n = get()
    print("%s, %s, %s" % (m, s, n))


outer()
```

You can access global variables using the `global` keyword.